# Light above back door, what is this light for?

Tags: electrical

There is a a small light with a red jeweled cover installed above the back door in my townhouse, I removed the cover to see that it is a small light bulb with 14 awg wire, any ideas?

Comment: How old is the townhouse? Was it originally a commercial establishment of some sort? Have you found a switch that controls the light?

Comment: What turns the light on and off? That general form factor is consistent with some sort of pilot/indicator light, BTW